# How can I set up the TE14XX MATLAB and Simulink licenses for use with TwinCAT3 XAE and XAR?

Tags: twincat

I need to purchase licenses for TE14xx to establish a connection between MATLAB, Simulink, and TwinCAT. However, I have encountered various situations, and I believe there might be alternative methods available.

Here are the primary options I've considered:

1. PC-bound licenses: One approach is to purchase licenses that are tightly bound to the hardware of your PC. This configuration allows for a stand-alone setup but might raise concerns about flexibility and portability.

[image]

2. USB dongle licenses: An alternative is obtaining licenses that are stored on a USB dongle. This method should allow for stand-alone use while potentially offering the advantage of moving the setup to different PCs with compatible hardware.

[image]

3. EtherCAT-based licensing: I've heard of the possibility of licensing access through EtherCAT, utilizing an "EtherCAT Terminal EL6070" in conjunction with an EK1100 terminal. Can anyone share their experiences with this method, including its effectiveness and any potential pitfalls?

[image]

While most discussions tend to focus on integrating XAE and XAR into a local system, I'm curious about how these licensing configurations may apply when using them separately. Can you shed light on whether accessing licenses via TCP/IP is a viable option in this scenario, or if there are any proven workarounds?

[image]

Another way is to use USB Stick but where should import it? PC or IPC!

[image]

What will happen if we share licenses through EtherCAT via the EL6070 family and EK1100?

[image]

All the above ways are focused on a single license repository but what happens if we have multiple license dongles (the licenses are distributed on the dongles)?

[image]

I would appreciate any insights, advice, or experiences related to configuring these licenses for TE14XX, especially if they are based on practical use in similar scenarios. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Hey, don't forget that in Simulink you will need the Simulink Real-Time toolbox license too, and this toolbox works using a target PC where the model runs (speedgoat PC)... These PC's comes with several flavors and prices, but you will need the PC as well.

So, back to your diagram there will be a speedgoat machine (the target machine for the model) between the EtherCAT network and the MATLAB PC.

Also, if you are using the TWINCAT to just reproduce the ENI file needed for the communication, you don't need a license for that.